# SQL Alternative to For Loop

Tags: sql, ms-access, loops

I'm working with SQL in Access.  I'm not much of a programmer, but I'm familiar with using VBA as well as SQL basics.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the equivalent in SQL of a for loop used in Visual Basic.  I know this isn't "technically" possible in SQL and may not be the best method so I'm looking for advice.  I know it can be accomplished for i=1,2,3, etc. by using unions and repeating the query for each value.  This is inefficient and easily gets too complex to be evaluated.

Basically what I need is a method to query for i=1 then repeat and again output data for i=2 and so on.  Using group by i is not an option because there are several subqueries involved as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use loops in SQL. Start thinking in sets (of rows.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a lot of context, we can't provide a better answer, but you can accomplish something of a FOR loop in sql.

```
declare @ctr integer

set @ctr = 1

while @ctr < 1000
begin

--Do your logic

select @ctr = @ctr + 1

end
```

But this isn't a very efficient use of SQL.  You should be able to write what you need without iterating over it.  Think in SETS and you will get along better with your RDBMS.

Comment: I can't really provide the code, but here are more details.  I have a large query involving multiple subqueries and aggregation in the select statement.  These are pulling data from 6 tables.  I am querying for data from each of our production lines; therefore, I want the query to return results for line 1, line 2, etc.  There's a good chance your first solution is what I need, and I don't really have a database manager to answer to.

Comment: You say that you can't GROUP BY LINE, but I'm pretty sure you can.  That's the course you should pursue.  Regardless, I've given you a solution to exactly what you asked.  It's just not a good solution to your underlying problem.

Comment: Much appreciated!  I'll look into the group by line.  With all the subqueries I haven't figured out its proper use yet.

Answer (score 2):

OK what you need to accomplish is not really clear, I recommend posting your table structure and what you need to retrieve.

However, what you want "seems" to be doable using an IN statement.

```
select 
   * 
from 
   whatever 
where id IN (1,2,3)
```